# Synchronizing a usermode application to a kernel driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

We have a driver that schedules work using a timer (using `add_timer`). Whenever the work results in a change, an application should be notified of this change.
Currently this is done by providing a sysfs entry from the driver, that blocks a read operation until there is a change in the data.
(Please see the relevant code from the driver and the application in the code block below.)

I have inspected the source of most functions related to this in the linux kernel (4.14.98), and I did not notice any *obvious* problems in `dev_attr_show`, `sysfs_kf_seq_show`,`__vfs_read` and `vfs_read`.

However in `seq_read` the mutex `file->private_data->lock` is held for the duration of the `read`:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.14.98/source/fs/seq_file.c#L165

- Will this pose a problem?
- Are there any other (potential?) problems that I should be aware of?

Please note that:

- The data will change at least once per second, usually way faster
- The application should respond as soon as possible to a change in the data
- This runs in a controlled (embedded) environment

```
// driver.c
static DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(wq);
static int xxx_block_c = 0;

// driver calls this to notify the application that something changed (from a timer, `timer_list`)
void xxx_Persist(void)
{
  xxx_block_c = 1;
  wake_up_interruptible(&wq);
}

// Sysfs entry that blocks until there is a change in the data.
static ssize_t xxx_show(struct device *dev,
                 struct device_attribute *attr,
                 char *buf)
{
    wait_event_interruptible(wq, xxx_block_c != 0);
    xxx_block_c = 0;

    /* Remainder of the implementation */
}
```

```
//application.cpp
std::ifstream xxx;
xxx.open("xxx", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
while (true)
{
    xxx.clear();
    xxx.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
    xxx.read(data, size);
    /* Do something with data */
}
```

Comment: Why not use a pipe?

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Personally, I would use an `ioctl()`.  To me that seems more appropriate for an asynchronous event notification than `read()`, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  That would also work

Comment: Given that `struct file` is unique for each `open()`, the only "weird" case you have is `fd = open(...); fork(); read(fd);`. Here both the parent and the children will contend the same `file->private_data->lock`. This isn't an issue though, as soon as the first is done the second will proceed. Not sure, but the same might happen when sharing the `fd` through e.g. UNIX sockets.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy It has already been implemented like this, I am checking if the current setup could cause any problems.

Comment: There would be a problem if `xxx_show()` needed to return 4096 or more bytes, because then `xxx_show()` would be called more than once and you would miss one or more events.

Comment: It's also not thread-safe.  And since the two processes in @MarcoBonelli 's  `fork()` example share the same file description, it's not multi-process safe either.  Two processes or threads that interleave their `seekg()` and `read()` calls will leave the file's current position at the end of the amount of data read from the first `read()` for the second `read()` - the second `read()` will not be done from the start of the file.  So if you have multiple threads or multiple parent/child processes sharing that file descriptor, it's a broken implementation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle well, this is true for any regular file descriptor... it's up to the application to not mess things up.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Well, OP did ask *Are there any other (potential?) problems that I should be aware of?*  Given the timing required to trigger any bugs, it's possible such code would pass testing, and problems only intermittently appear on customer's systems (for other readers - I know you know that...).  I would have just used low-level `open()` and then [`pread()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pread.html) on the file descriptor and gotten faster, unbuffered, thread-safe reading directly...

Comment: Are `wq` and `xxx_block_c` actually statically allocated as shown, or was that just for illustrative purposes? They should really be in the device private data structure. Also, there is a race condition on accessing `xxx_block_c` between driver calls to `xxx_Persist` and sysfs file handling calls to `xxx_show`. Ideally, checking and modification of `xxx_block_c` should be done atomically (for example by using a spin lock).

Comment: @IanAbbott yes, they are actually statically allocated. The entire driver was written to be a single-instance, single-task driver. As for the race condition, can you please elaborate on that?